# Azure Key Vault incorrectly creating Compound Identity

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

In Azure Key Vault policies I wanted to add ADF.
Given below is the command(executed from pipeline). But after creation it is showing as 'compound identity' with an 'on behalf of' text and it is not working. When I manually add ADF to policies it shows as 'application' and it works. How can I make the powershell create 'Application' identity?

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -PermissionsToSecrets get -ApplicationId $appId -ObjectId $objectId
```

Full script

```
$rgName='myRG'
$storageAccountName='MyStorage'
$secretName='myKey'
$keyVaultName='myKv'
$adfName='myADF'

Write-Host "Adding data lake storage Key to key vault"

$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey  -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$secretVal = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $storageAccountKey -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -PermissionsToSecrets get -ApplicationId $appId -ObjectId $objectId

Write-Host "completed adding key"

Write-Host "Adding access policy to key vault"
$objectId=(Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $adfName).Identity.PrincipalId
$appId = (Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectId).ApplicationId
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrong command was given. Given below is the correct. [Explained in 'Example 2: Grant permissions for an application service principal to read and write secrets'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-3.5.0)

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -ServicePrincipalName $appId -PermissionsToSecrets Get
```

Comment: Thanks for the kindly sharing, you could mark your reply as an answer, which will also help others in the community