# Azure Key Vault: How to validate user has access

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

When a user calls my API I want to validate if that user has access to my Azure Key Vault.

The API is running in an app service and this app service has been granted access to the key vault but I want to make certain the user calling the API also has been granted access to the key vault.

Does Azure SDK provide a way of getting the access policies for a key vault?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [on behalf access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#active-directory-authentication), only users which have access to the KeyVault can gain access through your API. In this case, you would give the API only "delegated" access to KeyVault, so it only works with a user.

> **User plus application access**: The application accesses Key Vault on behalf of a signed-in user. Examples of this type of access include Azure PowerShell and the Azure portal. User access is granted in two ways. Users can access Key Vault from any application, or they must use a specific application (referred to as compound identity).

Ideally, you would give access to an AD Group, and add your users to this group. Giving individual users access is [discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-security#identity-and-access-management).

[This tutorial](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/05/17/getting-it-right-key-vault-access-policies) also touches on what you desire.

> This is for On-Behalf-Of Authorization scenarios which means that authorization is granted to a specific user only via a specific application. Without other Access Policies, the user cannot access the Key Vault without the app, and the app cannot access the Key Vault without the user.  Most organizations will not use this feature, but I know that some have.

[image: Compound identity]
(Image taken from [Azure Key Vault incorrectly creating Compound Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571433/azure-key-vault-incorrectly-creating-compound-identity))

Comment: How do I configure the Azure key vault to require both user and application access?
The problem with using an AD group to validate access to an API is a developer could remove the code that does that check and publish to production then get the key. I need the vault itself to require both user and application access.

Comment: Look for "compound identity" - e.g. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49362

Comment: Shoud look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3beup.png

Comment: Can you include steps on how to create a "compound identity"? I've been looking high and low but can't find any examples.